# The use of std::throw_with_nested with regard to C++

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

There is very little information on the internet with regard to std::throw_with_nested and C++, and how it should be used. I currently implement it throughout all my code but is this bad practice or perfectly okay? Or should I be doing it somehow differently? I would love to hear the opinions of others on this matter, thank you. I apologize if there is another thread on this question but I could only find very little. An example of my code is below:

```
void GkCrypto::Crypto::generateRandomBytes(unsigned char *buf)
{
    try {
        if (1 != RAND_bytes(buf, sizeof(buf))) {
            handleErrors();
        }
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::throw_with_nested(std::runtime_error(e.what()));
    }
}

void GkCrypto::Crypto::handleErrors()
{
    unsigned long errCode;

    std::cerr << gettext("An error has occured!") << std::endl;
    while (errCode = ERR_get_error()) {
        char *err = ERR_error_string(errCode, NULL);
        std::cerr << err << std::endl;
        char *errBuf = NULL;
        std::sprintf(errBuf, gettext("An error has occured! Error:\n\n %s\n"), err);
        throw std::runtime_error(errBuf);
    }

    abort();
}
```

Comment: `throw_with_nested` really only makes sense to call in a `catch` statement...

Comment: Ah yes, good point! I should use just a typical throw in that part.

Comment: [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/throw_with_nested) example code is quite good/explanatory. What you're doing doesn't make any sense. Why catch a `runtime_error` just to construct an identical one out of it and rethrow it as a nested exception with 2 identical exceptions in it?

Comment: @David, ohh, I see what you mean. Rethrowing exceptions is a relatively new concept to me and I'm only starting to get a grasp on it through your comments. Because there are so few C++ examples it seems, would it help to look up Java examples? That's how I learn best and I believe that language has a similar feature, from what I hear.

Comment: I don't know what equivalent java has to this, but if you don't know this already, you're investigating a part of the language that probably 0.1% of users are even aware exists, and it is basically not used in any codebase anywhere. That doesn't mean it's a bad tool to use though...